Database Migration Failed in laravel
Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->string('title');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->unsignedInteger('salary');
    $table->string('location');
    $table->string('category');
    $table->enum('experience', ['entry', 'intermediate', 'senior']);
    $table->timestamps();
});

I've tried to seed the database with a factory using php artisan migrate:refresh --seed but i get this error:
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'jobs' already exists (Connection: mysql, SQL: create table `jobs` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `title` varchar(255) not null, `description` text not null, `salary` int unsigned not null, `location` varchar(255) not null, `category` varchar(255) not null, `experience` enum('entry', 'intermediate', 'senior') not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')


Welcome to SO.  The error message is pretty clear - it tells you the table you're trying to create already exists.  php artisan migrate:refresh rolls back all migrations using the down() methods of each before rerunning the up(), so it seems like that isn't working for the jobs table.  Do you have  down() method in that migration? Were there any other errors about failing to drop that table?

The error occurs because a table named jobs already exists in your database. This table is automatically created by Laravel when you use queues. It stores information about queued jobs that are processed asynchronously, including details like the job status, the number of attempts, and other data related to the queue system.
Since Laravel uses the jobs table for its own purposes, it's recommended to choose a different name for your table that will store job-related information, such as job_positions, vacancies, or employee_jobs. This will help you avoid conflicts and keep the queue system functioning properly.
